# Downloading files from Firebase | App works in debug but not release mode

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-storage

I'm trying to download all the files in a Firebase storage directory named 1.pdf, 2.pdf ...
The code works in debug mode, however doesn't work in release. I've been stuck on this all day. 
I think it could be threading from another class, but I have no clue to be honest.

Code to get file from Firebase:

```
   for (int i = 1; i < 10000; i++) {
        StorageReference ref = storageRef.child("FirstTimeForms/" + i + ".pdf");
        File localFile = File.createTempFile("Form", ".pdf");
        FileDownloadTask dm = ref.getFile(localFile);
        int fileSize = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(localFile.length()/1024));

        if(fileSize > 0){
            fileManager.copyFile(localFile, new File("/sdcard/Download/Forms/" + i + ".pdf"));
        }else{
            return;
        }
    }
```

Code to copy the file downloaded from Cache to SD

```
  FileChannel inChannel = new FileInputStream(src).getChannel();
        FileChannel outChannel = new FileOutputStream(dst).getChannel();
        try
        {
            inChannel.transferTo(0, inChannel.size(), outChannel);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (inChannel != null)
                inChannel.close();
            if (outChannel != null)
                outChannel.close();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Add these in your proguard-rules.pro

```
-keep class com.firebase.** { *; }
-keepattributes *Annotation*
-keepattributes Signature

-keep class YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME.YourActivity { *; }
```

Comment: I've never edited the proguard rules before. But think I did it correctly, by pasting them in and rebuilding. Is this correct?

Comment: I updated my answer, hope this will work, try again